# Realm Nested Query - Counting objects where at least one item of an object's collection satisfies a condition

Tags: android, realm

I have two Realm objects, Ticket and Message.

```
public class Ticket extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    private RealmList<Message> messages;
}

public class Message extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private Long id;
    private String text;
    private boolean read;
}
```

I'd like to return a count of tickets which have at least one unread message. In this example scenario, tickets 1 and 3 will be counted, but not ticket 2 since both messages have been read:

```
Ticket 1    
    - Message 1: Read
    - Message 2: Unread
Ticket 2
    - Message 1: Read
    - Message 2: Read
Ticket 3
    - Message 1: Unread
    - Message 2: Unread
```

Is this possible with a nested query in realm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is this

```
RealmResults<Ticket> tickets = realm.where(Ticket.class)
                                .equalTo("messages.read", false)
                                .findAll();
```

For further information please visit [Link Queries](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries)